# Is there any special API in Windows 8 to Mount ISO files?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8, windows-8.1

As you may know Windows Explorer allows to mount ISO files to a virtual drive.
Is there any API which can be used to do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323680(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are PowerShell cmdlets good enough?  http://superuser.com/a/499265

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: Looks like a good starting point.  Probably `AttachVirtualDisk` is the particular function needed for mounting?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes. Meant to link to `AttachVirtualDisk` but copied from wrong tab.

Comment: Looks like there's a WMI-based approach, using `MSFT_DiskImage` and `MSFT_DiskImageToVolume`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Seems like `MSFT_Disk*` uses `AttachVirtualDisk` and `OpenVirtualDisk` internally.

Comment: @Sani: Probably so... but WMI also allows finding where the image got mounted, which appears to be an open question with the direction API call.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes. My comment was more of an observation. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The native function call [`AttachVirtualDisk`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323692(v=vs.85).aspx).

However, if you are using C# like your tags suggest it may be easier to just [call out to PowerShell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation) and use its wrapper around that function [`Mount-DiskImage`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848706.aspx)

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace IsoMountTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isoPath = @"C:\Foo\bar.iso";
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddCommand("Mount-DiskImage").AddParameter("ImagePath", isoPath).Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```