# Mounting ISO programmatically not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to mount an ISO image programmatically, but it is not working. I am using the PowerShell Mount-DiskImage command. Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath" + imageFile;
```

The reason I need to mount the ISO image is so I can simply read the volume label of the ISO. I have not found any other way to do that using C#. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the error you get. "is not working" isn't helpful. And don't forget to place the "imageFile" in quotes if there is any space in the path.

Comment: I don't get an error, I get nothing at all. The next portion of my code looks at the ISO to get the mounted drive's volume label and then displays it in a textbox. The imageFile text is a variable representing the full path and filename of the ISO.

Comment: Are you redirecting stdErr and stdOut? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No, I am not redirecting anything.

Comment: This may resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582801/696808

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a simple space after the `ImagePath` argument and before the end quotes

```
startInfo.Arguments = "Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath " + imageFile;
```

Add the quotes around the imagePath to cover any spaces in the path itself.

```
startInfo.Arguments = "Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath \"" + imageFile + "\"";
```

Comment: Adding the space did not fix the issue.

Comment: @Tornado726 add the quotes around the ImagePath to make sure spaces are accounted for. And if it still fails, run the powershell command first to see if it actually works. If it doesn't.. provide the error message

Comment: I ran the Mount-DiskImage command manually in PowerShell, and it mounted without issue.

Comment: Can you post the complete code that shows how you are running the startinfo object along with the errors. You can remove the line that hides the ProcessWindow

Comment: `imageFile` should be double-quoted as single quotation mark is a valid path character: `startInfo.Arguments = "Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath \"" + imageFile + "\"";`

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a very important part: Process.Start(startInfo);